# NullPointerException warning in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
 public void dfs(){
        LinkedList<BinaryNode> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
        linkedList.add(root);

        while(!linkedList.isEmpty()){
            BinaryNode currentNode = linkedList.pollLast();

            if(currentNode.getRight() != null){
                linkedList.add(currentNode.getRight());
            }

            if(currentNode.getLeft() != null){
                linkedList.add(currentNode.getLeft());
            }

            System.out.println(currentNode.getNumber());
        }
    }
```

`if(currentNode.getRight() != null)` is giving me a warning in IntelliJ

> Method invocation 'getRight' may produce NullPointerException

Can someone give me an example of how I might get a NullPointerException.

The BinaryTree class has only one constructor

```
public class BinaryTree {
    private BinaryNode root;

    public BinaryTree(BinaryNode root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    // rest of code here including bfs/dfs algorithms
}
```

also here is the Node class:

```
public class BinaryNode {
    private int number;
    private BinaryNode left;
    private BinaryNode right;

    public BinaryNode(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    //boilerplate code here
}
```

Comment: You can write `dfs()` recursively to avoid the linked list altogether, and this is how it is usually done.

Comment: I understand but I'm practicing the iterative way. This is just practice.. I'm not trying to implement anything. Recursion is straight forward and easy to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for [pollLast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#pollLast--) mention:

```
Retrieves and removes the last element of this list, or returns null if this list is empty.
```

You should try checking first that the return is not a null. Example:

```
BinaryNode currentNode = linkedList.pollLast();
if(currentNode != null && currentNode.getRight() != null)
```

Comment: why would the preceding `while(!linkedList.isEmpty()){` not be sufficient?

Comment: Oh okay.. I understand now. I would want to use pop() then since pollLast can return a null.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Though the `while` loop is guarded at time of entry, the `LinkedList` data structure could be possibly modified (e.g. if more than one thread is accessing it) before `pollLast()` is called on it, and a `null` could be returned. IntelliJ is highlighting this as a warning, with the intention of aiding the developer in addressing a potential bug in code.

Comment: Hmm, the variable is local.  To me it looks like over zealous reporting by IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this warning because the below variable,

```
BinaryNode currentNode = linkedList.pollLast();
```

Can be null at any given time, thus

```
if(currentNode.getRight() != null){
    linkedList.add(currentNode.getRight());
}
```

Will throw a null pointer exception if the value of `currentNode` is null.

It can be avoided by checking if the value of `currentNode` is null, below, like so:

```
   while(!linkedList.isEmpty()){
        BinaryNode currentNode = linkedList.pollLast();

        if (currentNode != null) { //Null check is here
            if(currentNode.getRight() != null){
                linkedList.add(currentNode.getRight());
            }

            if(currentNode.getLeft() != null){
                linkedList.add(currentNode.getLeft());
            }

            System.out.println(currentNode.getNumber());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or `while ((currentNode = linkedList.pollLast()) != null)`, with suitable adjustments.